# Opt out from getting public beta versions of OS X

Tags: macos

Until now, I used to be a public beta tester on OS X, so I opted in for beta versions and the current OS X version is 10.11.1 Beta (15B38b) (as for now, it's the latest public beta version).

Since I do not want to receive any updates regarding public beta versions through App Store, I opted out through the settings of the Mac. So, I want to ask whether I have to perform a fresh install of the final release of El Capitan or I am going to get any new update (regarding the final release) through Mac App Store when it is released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was on the public beta also! I was able to go to the public release just by updating from the App Store. It kept all my information!

Comment: So, you reverted from some El Capitan public beta version to the official release (which you downloaded through the Mac App Store) and  all your files were just in their place?

Comment: Correct. The only feature that was removed was the feedback app! It was only needed for the beta though.